# Use vscode to run r programs with R 4.0.5 installed

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I have vscode and the R extension installed as well as R 4.0.5 on my computer ,but when I run the code in vscode i get this error message

> 'Rscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

what do I need to do so I can run R code in vscode.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add the directory containing `R` and `RScript` to your PATH variable. In Linux/MacOS you can add the following line to your ~/.bashrc file:

```
# Change /usr/local/bin/ to where R is located
PATH=“/usr/local/bin/:$PATH"
```

In Windows follow the steps in the article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee537574(v=office.14)
The installation directory in Windows is probably something like 'C:/Program Files/R’.